# Golang enqueue a method with task queues

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, task-queue

I am new to golang and i'm using this taskqueue library [google.golang.org/appengine/taskqueue](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/appengine/taskqueue) to enqueue tasks. I have tried enqueing an api call, which looks like this(ie., a PUT api call)

```
 taskqueue.Task{
  Path:    fmt.Sprintf(<endpoint>),
  Method:  "PUT",
  Payload: payload
}
```

But I want to know how do i enqueue any other method which does things apart from a rest call. Say, I have this below method **printHello** which i want to be enqueued and executed later in the pipeline.
Is there any way to do that with taskqueues?

```
  func printHello(msg string){
    log.Infof("Doing some tasks here");
   }
```

I am using golang 1.11.13

Comment: Looks like with `TaskQueue` it is not possible to perform tasks other than HTTP Reuqests. Also note that `TaskQueue` is meant to perform tasks outside of the user request. Alternatively you can explore Timers etc.

Answer (score 0):

With Task Queue, you use [Cloud Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) Google Cloud product that enqueue the HTTP calls. If you want to call your printHello function, it must be HTTP callable (thus in a webserver, reachable publicly. Can be secured with IAM on Google Coud).

You can't enqueue internal function call.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now, i tried enqueing a rest api call to localhost, but different port number from the one where app is running. So i gave absolute path as such(http://localhost:9200/es/index) . This is not working, but relative path within the app works. Is there some restriction like this?

Comment: Cloud Task is a service in the Cloud and call API Endpoint through internet. How your `localhost` URL will be resolved? Cloud Task don't know how to reach your workstation! Use your public IP and be sure that your internal router (your internet box) route the traffic to your workstation?